# Given a set, show it belongs to sigma algebra (Borel)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, borel-sets

Suppose you have the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. I am given the set/region
$$
A = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, \phi(x) \leq \epsilon\right\}.
$$

> 1. Does this set belong to the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
> 2. If this is true only for some $\phi$ what conditions shall it satisfy?

I know how to prove that a set *is* a sigma algebra. Not sure about how to show that a set belongs to one.

## Answer following the comments

Suppose $\phi$ is a measurable function. This means that for any set $E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ we have that its pre-image under $\phi$ is an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
$$
\phi^{-1}(E) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, \phi(x) \in E\} \in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n).
$$
Now if we take $E = [0, \epsilon]$ then $\phi$ measurable means that
$$
\phi^{-1}([0, \epsilon]) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, \phi(x) \leq \epsilon\}
$$
is an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But this set is exactly $A$, so $A$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$-measurable.

Comment: Perhaps I could show $A$ is (or isn't) an open set..

Comment: For $A$ to be open, the following must be true: For every $x\in A$, there exists $\delta(x)\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that every $y\in A$ with $d(x, y) < \delta(x)$  belongs to $A$

Comment: If $\varphi $ is measurable, then so is $A$ (by definition), an if $\varphi $ is not measurable, then $A$ may be not measurable.

Comment: @Surb What definition of measurability are you using? Cause the only one I know is $A$ is measurable if $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: A non-measurable example: Take a non-measurable subset $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and define $\phi=1-\mathbb{1}_M$. For $\epsilon < 1$ you have $A=M$.

Comment: @Surb as I am quite new to measure theory, do you mind writing a full answer?

Comment: My comment is already a full answer.

Comment: @Surb My bad, I guess I am a bit puzzled as to why $A$ is measurable by definition if $\phi$ is measurable

Comment: Definition I use is $\varphi $ is measurable $\iff$ $\{x\mid \varphi (x)\leq \alpha \}$ measurable for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Surb I have written an answer in the question following your remarks. Do you mind having a look?

Comment: your proof is correct.